# How to load image in background of jumbotron in my django project?

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have been stuck in this for quite a while now. I am doing a project in Django in which I need to put an image in the background in the jumbotron.

### home.html

```
 {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
    <header>
      <style>
        .jumbotron {
        background-image: url('{{STATIC_URL}}blog/home-bg.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
      }
      </style>
    </header>
    <!-- JUMBOTRON -->
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome To CodeBlog</h1>  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
        <a href="{% url 'blog-about' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    //some more lines of code
    {% endblock %}
```

[image]

**home-bg.jpg is present in the static/blog/home-bg.jpg**

### settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

But still, I am not getting what is expected. I am using Bootstrap4 and Django 2.2

Comment: try putting the absolute path to the image.Also you may be missing a `/` at  `url('{{STATIC_URL}}/blog/home-bg.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    background: url("/static/img/sample.jpeg") 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;     
}
```

use like this. it will work.